# Why do we still use shell commands to program?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell, heroku

As a beginner & new developer attempting to learn the ropes, I am curious why we still use package managers, shell commands, and all of these things that seem like the early DOS days.

Wouldn't it seem more logical to have a GUI to simply set up an app on Heroku from Github without having to always fix all of your local environment errors and updating gems, etc?

May be a stupid question, but truly curious why it hasn't changed.

Comment: Because it will cost too much time to change?  I don't know why others are voting you down for this question. Maybe they feel threatened?

Comment: How can I answer this without starting a flame war...
When I want something "my way", I code it "my way", so, develop your GUI.
Maybe you should go for other user friendly IDE's.
Eclipse, Netbeans, Visual Studio, Mongo pratically don't need messing around the CLI.
I really don't understand why so many people hate the CLI, but that's just me, born in the BBS days and messing around MS-DOS and later with Red Hat 5 *shigh*

Comment: I retract my comment about being threaten.  I suppose it is opinion based (but isn't everything?)